# Problem writing data from PrintStream to "Console as Process" and not "console as System.out" in Java

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder, printstream

in Java 8, windows 10, i have a text app, i want to open a console and write something there,

first try is:

```
    String [] cmd = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "start"};
    ProcessBuilder f = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    f.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = f.start();
    PrintStream printStream=new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream());
    //
    System.setOut(printStream);
    System.out.println("this write in CMD"); //did not work
```

second try is:

```
    printStream.println("this write in CMD");//did not work
```

Can any body Help?

Comment: The command `start` given to CMD.EXE causes your CMD.EXE to launch a new command window. That means you have 2 CMD.EXE processes and Java knows nothing of the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch `conhost.exe` instead, and write to the stdin of the retained Process, or if you redirect your output stream to the process writes with `System.out` will appear in the new console window:

```
String [] cmd = {"conhost.exe"};
ProcessBuilder f = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
f.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = f.start();
PrintStream printStream=new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream());
System.setOut(printStream);
System.out.println("dir");
```

Comment: thanks,i try to test it, but didnt work, just black cmd